# Implementation of piecewised function in python with numerical ODE solution. TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'OdeResult'

Tags: python, ode, numerical-computing

I have a reaction system whose mechanism is defined in the form of a nonlinear first-order ODE as:

d*x*(*t*)/d*t* = - *gaf*(1 - rho)(1 - exp(-*kt*))(*x*(*t*)^2 + *bx*(*t*))/(*cx*(*t*) + *p*)

where, *g*, *a*, *f*, *b*, *c*, *rho*, *k* and *p* are all constants.

I’m trying to compile a code in python to obtain the time trajectory of the variable *x*(*t*) from time *t*1 to time *t*f where the kinetic range of the profile is always preceded by a waiting period of 2 min before the reaction starts with constant *x*0 value in that period starting a time *t*0 = 0. My aim is to export the whole profile to excel (as .xlsx file) in regular spaced intervals of 2.5 secs as shown in the link to the figure below.

[Overall Trajectory Profile - Plotted Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGp2E.png)

I wish the system be defined in the form of a **piecewised function**, but when I run the code below in python it gives me the error: "float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'OdeResult'". I’m stuck here! Any suggestions on how to remedy this problem or alternatives?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = 1
rho = 0.1
r = 0.5
a = 0.08
x0 = 2
b = x0*(1/r - 1)
k = 1.0e-2
g = 0.138
b = 2
c = 1.11
p = 2.174

tau = (1/k)*np.log(f/(f-rho))    # Inhibition time (induction period)

t0 = 0
ti = 120
t1 = ti + tau
tf = 1000
delta_t = 2.5
t_end = tf + delta_t
dt = 1.0e-5
t_eval=np.arange(t0, t_end, dt)

def ode(t, x):
    return -g*a*f*(1-rho)*(1-np.exp(-k*t))*(x**2 + b*x)/(c*x + p)
sol = solve_ivp(ode, [t0, t_end], [x0], t_eval=t_eval, method='RK45')

plt.figure(figsize = (12, 4))
plt.subplot(121)
curve, = plt.plot(sol.t, sol.y[0])
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("x(t)")
plt.show()

t = np.arange(t0, tf, delta_t)

def x(t):
    if(t0 <= t <= ti): return x0    # Waiting period
    elif(ti < t < t1): return x0    # Lag period associated to 'tau' (inhibition period)
    else: return sol                # Dynamic range (problem here!!). TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'OdeResult'

y = []
for i in range(len(t)):
   y.append(x(t[i]))

plt.plot(t, y, c='red', ls='', ms=5, marker='.')
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_ylim([0, x0])
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `t_eval=t_eval` with `dense_output=True`. Then the returned `sol` object contains an interpolation function `sol` so that you could complete your `x` function as

```
    return sol.sol(t)[0]
```

You do not need an `else` branch if the branch before is concluded with a `return` statement.

You might want to include the derivative zero on the constant segment inside the ODE function, so that the `x(t)` function is not needed. Then you would get the desired values also direct with the instant evaluation using `t_eval` as done originally.

Comment: I'm not sure how your last suggestion could be implemented, but it is definitely the best choice to the piecewised representation. When <t_eval=t_eval> is replaced by <dense_output=True> the resulting solution is numerically less accurate than the original. I've changed the integration method to <method='LSODA'> which gave a much better agreement with the original profile. Yet, there are obvious differences. I would therefore be more interested on how to include the zero derivative inside the ODE function. If you could exemplify I'd be much appreciated. I'm new to python!

Comment: You would just insert `if t<t1: return 0` as the first line in the ODE function. That should give a solution of the desired shape, but otherwise different from what you had before.